# XML Invalid content was found starting with element. One of '{}' is expected

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I was validating an XSD against a XML document, and I get this error:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'artSpent:name'. One of
>   `'{"http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/lprog":name}'` is expected. [467]

Here is a XSD sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema version="1.0"
            xmlns:lprog="http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/lprog"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/lprog" 
            elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:element name="warehouse">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="ListSpent" 
                             type="lprog:TListSpent" 
                             maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>       

       <xsd:complexType name="ListSpent">
        <xsd:sequence >
            <xsd:element name="Spent" 
                         type="lprog:TSpent" 
                         maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>  

       <xsd:complexType name="TSpent">
        <xsd:sequence >
            <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="stock" type="lprog:TQtdArtigo" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>     
</xsd:schema>
```

---

And my XML sample

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <warehouse xmlns="http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/lprog"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/lprog 
                             TraXSD.xsd">

     <ListSpent xmlns:artSpent="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                artSpent:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="TraXSD.xsd">
        <Spent>
            <artSpent:name>Meat</artSpent:name>
            <artSpent:stock>2</artSpent:stock>
        </Spent>    
    </ListSpent>
</warehouse>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with both your XSD and your XML file, but the particular one causing the immediate error you cite in your question is due to you not establishing the `name` element properly in the `targetNamespace="http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/lprog"` of the governing XSD.  See how I do it in the working examples below...

The following corrected XSD will successfully validate the following corrected XML file.

### XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:lprog="http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/lprog"
            targetNamespace="http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/lprog" 
            elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xsd:element name="warehouse">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="ListSpent" type="lprog:ListSpent"
                     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>       

  <xsd:complexType name="ListSpent">
    <xsd:sequence >
      <xsd:element name="Spent" type="lprog:TSpent" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>  

  <xsd:complexType name="TSpent">
    <xsd:sequence >
      <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="stock" type="xsd:integer" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

### XML

**Using default namespace declaration:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<warehouse xmlns="http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/lprog"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/lprog TraXSD.xsd">
  <ListSpent>
    <Spent>
      <name>Meat</name>
      <stock>2</stock>
    </Spent>    
  </ListSpent>
</warehouse>
```

**Using explicit namespace prefixes:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lprog:warehouse xmlns:lprog="http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/lprog"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/lprog TraXSD.xsd">
  <lprog:ListSpent>
    <lprog:Spent>
      <lprog:name>Meat</lprog:name>
      <lprog:stock>2</lprog:stock>
    </lprog:Spent>    
  </lprog:ListSpent>
</lprog:warehouse>
```

Comment: But i really need to have a namespace in my XML, so i choose to use in name and stock

Comment: All of the elements in the XML I show above are, in fact, in the `http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/lprog` by default.   Would it help you to see them explicitly placed in that namespace via a namespace prefix?

Comment: yes... please ... I'm a bit confused about namespaces

Comment: I've updated the answer to show equivalent forms of the XML.  Both are valid against the same XSD.  Both have all elements in the `http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/lprog` namespace.